# View/Edit/Save data with multiple tabs/forms in ASP.NET MVC with one Edit/Save button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am newbie to the MVC world and I am trying to create a UI with multiple tabbed pages and each page has a view model associated with it. I need to be able to do the following

1. View all the forms data by navigating between tabs
2. A common edit for all the forms and data should render all the Tabs in edit mode and user should be able to edit data for all the form elements by navigating between Tabs randomly.
3. User should be able to save the Forms data (from all the tabs) to the database in one button click.

Could someone tell me how to achieve this with the best practice in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: A submit button/input only posts the controls within its enclosing `form` element, so if your trying to post back all the controls from multiple `forms` you would need to construct the name/values using javascript/jquery and post using ajax.

Comment: It looks like all suggestions point me to JQuery/Ajax, and I guess it is the way to go...so I am leaning it now...